# FFmpeg hls from multiple files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to create an HLS playlist with multiple audio streams. I have the following files:

```
- videoHD.mp4
- videoSD.mp4
- audioEN.mp4
- audioFR.mp4
- audioIT.mp4
```

How would I transmux these all together in an `ffmpeg` command to create an `HLS` playlist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update January 2018**

You can now create master playlists directly with FFmpeg using `master_pl_name` and `var_stream_map`. See the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls).

---

According to the Apple docs you don't mux them all together and you can't use a single HLS playlist.

You need playlists for each video and each audio track (eg: `hd/playlist.m3u8`, `sd/playlist.m3u8`, `en/playlist.m3u8` etc.) and a master playlist to link them all together. The master playlist controls the playback.

Here's an example with two video qualities and three audio tracks from the docs:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES, \
DEFAULT=YES,URI="eng/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="fre",NAME="Français",AUTOSELECT=YES, \
DEFAULT=NO,URI="fre/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="sp",NAME="Espanol",AUTOSELECT=YES, \
DEFAULT=NO,URI="sp/prog_index.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=195023,CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
lo/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=591680,CODECS="avc1.42e01e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
hi/prog_index.m3u8
```

`ffmpeg` didn't support variant playlists the last time I checked so you need to create each alternate playlist individually and manually create the master playlist.

Of course for all this to work the individual streams must be aligned or you'll have a lot of synchronization issues. You can try using `ffmpeg` with multiple I/O:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 \
    -map … -acodec … -vcodec … output1 \
    -map … -acodec … -vcodec … output2 \
    -map … -acodec … -vcodec … output3
```

each output being of type `HLS`.

Sources:

[About HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html)

[Technical Note TN2288](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-ALTERNATE_MEDIA)

[FFmpeg - Creating Multiple Outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs)